# How to prevent access to a page but allow query

Tags: views, redirection

I have a page defined by Views module.
(for example: http://namedomainnn.com/cvstaff)

However, I want user only allow to access using query command)
(for example: http://namedomainnn.com/cvstaff?name=user1)

How can I prevent any users to access without query.

Comment: Check query parameters present in URL(http://namedomainnn.com/cvstaff?name=user1) while accessing you page.
Use $_GET['name']. If it empty show access denied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply check that your **URL parameter exists and it's not empty** before loading your view:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_pre_view().
 */
function MY_MODULE_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {
  if ($view->name == 'MY_VIEW_NAME') {
    // If your URL parameter doesn't exist or it's empty, deny access.
    if (!isset($_GET['name']) || empty($_GET['name'])) {
      drupal_access_denied();
      exit();
    }
  }
}
```

So, accessing:

http://example.com/cvstaff?name=user will work.

http://example.com/cvstaff will show an *Access Denied* page.

Comment: I never write module and I should get the access to the server. Please let me know if this is correct: (a) create a folder "my_module_views_pre_view" in sites\all\modules  (b) and create a file  "my_module_views_pre_view.module" in that folder (c) copy the codes into the .module file, in the beginning of the file starts add php tag <?php